# How to config MongoDB to access from a domain name?

Tags: mongodb

I have a domain `mydoma.in` and a VPS running Bitnami with Apache and a MongoDB server that I can connect using IP:27017 (public IP, not internal IP). Using cloudflare, I was able to create a subdomain `db.mydoma.in` and point to the IP of my VPS. Since I have Apache on my VPS, accessing `db.mydoma.in` is successful and bring out the front html page. But I can not connect any mongodbclient to my MongoDB server using `db.mydoma.in:27017`, or even access `db.mydoma.in:27017` using webbrowser (I know normally it will complain that I'm using a wrong protocol). How can I achieve that? Reverse proxy is a different thing so I guest that's not the problem here. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is your mongod configured to bind to 0.0.0.0?

Comment: The bind_ip conf has been commented `# bind_ip = 127.0.0.1`, in fact I can connect to the server using my VPS static IP with IP:27017