# PHP + MongoDB from Subdomains

Tags: php, mongodb

From: http://www.example.com/

```
require_once('/home/site/www/vendor/autoload.php'); //mongdb library
$driverOptions = ["typeMap" => ['root' => 'array', 'document' => 'array']];
$conn = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017", [], $driverOptions );
```

works.

From: http://subdomain.example.com/

```
require_once('/home/site/www/vendor/autoload.php'); //the same mongdb library
$driverOptions = ["typeMap" => ['root' => 'array', 'document' => 'array']];
$conn = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017", [], $driverOptions );
```

fails.

Any idea why a subdomain wouldn't be able to reach MongoDB when the main domain and webroot has no issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53751920/how-to-config-mongodb-to-access-from-a-domain-name ( seems similar, but not resolved )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it was a foolish mistake.
My subdomain wasn't being instructed to use the newest version of PHP (7.4) like the main domain, so the mongodb extension wasn't being used. Hopefully this helps others.